# Como calcular distancia entre 2 direcciones python

Tags: python, python-3.x, geolocalización

lo que intento hacer es saber cuanto tiempo tomaria un automovil, moverse de un punto a otro tomando en cuenta la carretera, lo hice con la formula de Haversine pero no concuerda con lo que me regresa google maps

```
import math

lat1 = 31.78222
lon1 = -106.69147

lat2 = 31.78176
lon2 = -106.67623

rad = math.pi/180
dlat = lat2-lat1
dlon = lon2-lon1
R=6372.795477598
a=(math.sin(rad*dlat/2))**2 + math.cos(rad*lat1)*math.cos(rad*lat2)*(math.sin(rad*dlon/2))**2
distancia=2*R*math.asin(math.sqrt(a))
print(distancia)
```

alguno sabra alguna forma sin consultar tantas veces el API de google maps (creo que despues de ciertas llamadas nos empieza a cobrar)

Comment: Me parece que Google Maps calcula la distancias **por caminos**, mientras que Haversine la calcula en línea recta (bueno, la distancia usado el gran círculo sobre una esfera).

Comment: asi es, lo que busco es algo que lo calcule por caminos :(

Comment: Bueno, primero necesitas tener el camino. ¿Has visto si [OpenStreetMap](https://www.openstreetmap.org/) los tiene? Dado que te permiten editar colaborativamente el mapa, es posible que puedas sacar de ahi los caminos.

Comment: si, ya los tiene e igual he creado uno que no estaba